Understanding topological censorship: is something wrong with this example?
Earlier today I was discussing with someone about the possibility of space (not spacetime) being a torus, and how this is different from a sphere. For simplicity, let us assume spacetime is of the form $\mathbb{R} \times \Sigma$, with $\Sigma$ the spatial manifold. This is standard in globally hyperbolic spacetimes, which are my case of interest.
Now, I came up with an experiment that I believe could probe the topology of $\Sigma$. Namely, take a ridiculously long rope throughout spacetime and keep one of its ends fixed on Earth. Take a lap across spacetime by moving forward until you get back to Earth. When you do this, the rope will be wrapped around space. You can then join the ends and pull on the rope. If you can contract the rope to a point, space may be a sphere (or you got a "bad" loop on the torus). If you can't contract the rope, then space is a torus.
I know, however, that there is a result in general relativity known as topological censorship, which I believe to imply that the experiment above shouldn't be possible: you can't probe the topology of spacetime. However, I do not know the details of this result and never studied it before.
This leads to my question: is this experiment possible? If not, why? If it is, how does it bypass topological censorship?
I believe this might be related to the fact that my experiment doesn't give the exact topology, but rather only allows you to falsify whether space is simply-connected. However, I'm not sufficiently familiar with topological censorship to be sure.

Regardless of this conjecture, people do observational studies for evidence of non-trivial topology on cosmological scales using the CMB, eg: https://physics.aps.org/articles/v17/74

So, basically, your experiment measures the first homotopy group of a space-like hypersurface. But to contract it, you need the time dimension to do so. What would happen if there's a black hole enclosed by the rope?

@JeanbaptisteRoux It seems to me that it would snap the rope, which is surely a limitation of the experiment

Actually, it is a bit more complicated, since an outside observer will never see the rope cross the event horizon

@NíckolasAlves This was my very point, in this experiment, one could mistake a simple black hole for a "nontrivial topology of the universe". This is even worse if the rope encloses several black holes.

I've wondered this too. Perhaps an important hint is that the theorem in Friedman et al. (1993) requires an asymptotically flat spacetime and relates to causal curves from $\mathscr{I}^-$ to $\mathscr{I}^+$, neither of which is applicable to a universe with nontrivial global topology.

Topological censorship is about asymptotically flat initial data of (possibly) nontrivial topology (such as initial data for $\mathbb{RP}^3$ geon). It does not prohibit probing such things as spatial topology of the FLRW universe.
